# Sales and Trends statistics for "yesterday"

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

Since changed Sales and Trends interface on iTunes Connect, I can't find my yesterday's statistic. I'm just able to see least 3 day's (yesterday not including) statistics.
How can I see how much downloads/earnings I had yesterday?

P.S: Daily report section is also not works propably. Sales on daily reports and sales on iTunes Connect iphone app are different.

Answer (score 0):

Itunes Connect doesn't seem to allow for viewing one day anymore.
If you're having trouble with iTunes connect, I suggest you use this free iOS app to track sales: https://github.com/omz/Appsales-Mobile

I have used it for years and it's great. It estimates r